Popup message with PHP session flags problem
I would like to display a popup message on a HTML page only if I had clicked on a button and had sent successfully a form from another one. I tried to do that with PHP sessions (including JavaScript of course), and I see everything is OK, but the page where's the popup on, display the popup also when I directly go to it, not from the form submission's page. I would like to display it only, when I go from the form's page with successful form sending.
Here's the form submission page code (form.php):
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
//database

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "Correctly saved";
        $_SESSION['fromForm'] = true;
        header('Location: secondpage.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="field1" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Here's the popup message's page code (second.php)
<?php
session_start();
?>
<body>

<div id="popupMessage" class="popup-message">
    <span class="popup-icon">!</span>
    <span class="popup-text" id="popupText"></span>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['fromFORM']) && $_SESSION['fromFORM'] === true) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
             'showPopupMessage("' . $_SESSION['successMessage'] . '");',
             '</script>';
        unset($_SESSION['successMessage']);
    }
    unset($_SESSION['fromFORM']);
}
?>

<script src="script.js"></script>

And the JavaScript file (script.js):
function showPopupMessage(message) {
    const popup = document.getElementById('popupMessage');
    const popupText = document.getElementById('popupText');
    popupText.textContent = message;
    popup.classList.add('show');

    setTimeout(() => {
        popup.classList.remove('show');
    }, 3000); // The message will disappear after 3 seconds
}


second.php != secondpage.php

You need to put <script src="script.js"></script> before the script that tries to call the function. Aren't you getting an error message in the console saying that the function isn't defined?

It's before that. The script.js make a seperate file, so it's invited afterwards.

You have to load script.js before you try to call the functions it defines. So move <script src="script.js"></script> up in your script.
And use json_encode() to encode the value of the message in case it contains special characters that need to be escaped.
<?php
session_start();
?>
<body>

<div id="popupMessage" class="popup-message">
    <span class="popup-icon">!</span>
    <span class="popup-text" id="popupText"></span>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['fromFORM']) && $_SESSION['fromFORM'] === true) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
             'showPopupMessage(' . json_encode($_SESSION['successMessage']) . ');',
             '</script>';
        unset($_SESSION['successMessage']);
    }
    unset($_SESSION['fromFORM']);
}
?>

